# Paypal Android SDK in PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT always shows 'TRANSACTION_REFUSED'

Tags: android, paypal, transactions

I successfully completed the Paypal sandbox account testing. But when I came into production environment it always shows the error:'TRANSACTION REFUSED'. Can anyone please tell me why its happening?

What is  App redirect URLs and return URL? Is it necessary to give both while creating an app in developer.paypal.com?

here is what my Logcat shows:

```
07-02 14:34:37.382: E/n(274): com.paypal.android.p2pmobile not found.
07-02 14:34:37.732: D/dalvikvm(274): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 9617 objects / 730512 bytes in 117ms
07-02 14:34:40.493: W/KeyCharacterMap(274): No keyboard for id 0
07-02 14:34:40.493: W/KeyCharacterMap(274): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
07-02 14:34:42.132: D/NativeCrypto(274): Freeing OpenSSL session
07-02 14:34:45.221: D/NativeCrypto(274): Freeing OpenSSL session
07-02 14:34:45.221: D/NativeCrypto(274): Freeing OpenSSL session
07-02 14:34:45.231: D/dalvikvm(274): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9678 objects / 719704 bytes in 212ms
07-02 14:35:01.942: W/paypal.sdk(274): W SN:16 PayPal Debug-ID: c071e094f8f48 [live, 2.2.2;release]
07-02 14:35:05.161: W/paypal.sdk(274): Y SN:19 PayPal Debug-ID: 70dc1489f9faa [live, 2.2.2;release]
07-02 14:35:05.171: E/paypal.sdk(274): request failure with http statusCode:400,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
07-02 14:35:05.171: E/paypal.sdk(274): request failed with server response:{"name":"TRANSACTION_REFUSED","message":"The request was refused.{0}","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#TRANSACTION_REFUSED","debug_id":"70dc1489f9faa"}
07-02 14:35:05.171: E/PayPalService(274): TRANSACTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the PayPal Debug-ID that you provided - the error indicates that the payer account may not be associated with a usable funding source. Can you check the payer account you are using?

Comment: Thank You Matt for your answer.i will check.